# The second call to D3 reusable line chart only draws axes but not lines

Tags: d3.js, charts

I am trying to make a line chart where two lines are drawn, one line is displayed before today's date and the other is displayed after today's date, for that I am using D3's clip path, and the users can click on buttons to update the chart.  That part works but when I try to make that code reusable since I wanted a second chart below the first, and when I pass a second container to the same chart function (i.e. #graph1 for chart 1 and #graph2 for chart 2) it only draws the axes but not the lines for the second graph (the first one still works), could someone point me in the right direction? Thank you.
Below is my code:

```
function chart(selection) {
       selection.each(function(data) {

      var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg").data([data]);

      // Update the outer dimensions.
      svg.attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height);

      // Update the inner dimensions.
      var g = svg.select("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      if(alreadyClicked==true){

         svg.select("#clip-before rect")
         .transition().duration(400)
         .attr("width", xScale(parsedate(today)))
         .attr("height", height- margin.top - margin.bottom);

         svg.select("#clip-after rect")
         .transition().duration(400)
         .attr("x", xScale(parsedate(today)))
         .attr("width", width-xScale(parsedate(today)))
         .attr("height", height- margin.top - margin.bottom);

         svg.selectAll("path.line-after")
         .data(data).transition()
         .duration(400).attr("d", line_after(data));

         svg.selectAll("path.line-before")
         .data(data).transition()
         .duration(400).attr("d", line_before(data));


      }else{
        g.append("clipPath")
              .attr("id", "clip-before")
              .append("rect")
              .attr("width", xScale(parsedate(today)))
              .attr("height", height- margin.top - margin.bottom);

         g.append("clipPath")
              .attr("id", "clip-after")
              .append("rect")
              .attr("x", xScale(parsedate(today)))
              .attr("width", width-xScale(parsedate(today)))
              .attr("height", height- margin.top - margin.bottom);

        g.selectAll(".line")
              .data(["after"])
              .enter().append("path")
              .attr("class", function(d) { return "line-" + d; })
              .attr("clip-path", function(d) { return "url(#clip-" + d + ")"; })
              .attr("d", line_after(data));

         g.selectAll(".line")
              .data(["before"])
              .enter().append("path")
              .attr("class", function(d) { return "line-" + d; })
              .attr("clip-path", function(d) { return "url(#clip-" + d + ")"; })
              .attr("d", line_before(data));


      }





    // Add the X Axis
      g.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis");


      svg.select(".x.axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,300)").transition().duration(400).call(xAxis);

      g.selectAll(".x.axis text")  // select all the text elements for the xaxis
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
             return "translate(" + this.getBBox().height*-2 + "," + this.getBBox().height + ")rotate(-45)";
         });

      // Add the Y Axis
      g.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis"); 

      svg.select(".y.axis").transition().duration(400).call(yAxis);


  }); //end selection.each
}//end chart
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co) or in the inline code sample here on SO? It would help us play with it to try our solutions out. For example, I suspect it is to do with ids, but I can't tell for sure without playing with it to see.

Comment: Is my code on github ok? since I have a repo already. here is the viz:  http://jhjanicki.github.io/reusable-line-chart/ and here is the code https://github.com/jhjanicki/reusable-line-chart  thanks!

Comment: There are few bugs in your code, those are making this noise. We've to change/write code in a reusable manner. If you are interested, then we'll explain what's wrong. :D

Comment: Ya that would be great! I am self-taught in this field and am slowly learning so any comments that I could learn from would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
/**
* PredictGraph code start
*/
(function () {
 d3.PredictGraph = function() {
     // OPTIONS 
   // (manipulated with getters and setters below)
   var margin = {top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 60},
    width = getWidth($(window).width()),
    height = 450,
    xValue = function(d) { return d.date; },
    yValue = function(d) { return d.actualvalue; },
    yValue2= function(d) { return d.predictedvalue;},  
    xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    xAxis = xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale)
   .orient("bottom").ticks(10).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d")), //this is where the date is formatted for the axis,
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale)
   .orient("left").ticks(10),
    line = d3.svg.line().x(X).y(Y),
    line_before= d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.date);})
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.actualvalue);
       }),
    line_after= d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.date);})
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.predictedvalue);})
    today= moment()._d, //date object
    formatDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d"),
    todayFormatted = formatDate(moment()._d),
    alreadyClicked=false;
   function chart(selection) {
  selection.each(function(data) {
  console.log(this);
  var max_actual = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.actualvalue;} ); //before
  var max_predicted = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.predictedvalue;} ); //after
  var max = Math.max(max_actual, max_predicted); //overall
  var min_actual = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.actualvalue;} ); //before
  var min_predicted = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.predictedvalue;} ); //after
  var min = Math.min(min_actual, min_predicted);     
  var parsedate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;  
  // to convert date from a formated string into a date object
   data.forEach(function(d) {d.date = parsedate(d.date);});     
    // Update the x-scale.
    xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; })).range([0, width- margin.left - margin.right]);
    // Update the y-scale.
    yScale.domain([min,max]).range([height- margin.top - margin.bottom,0]);
    // Select the svg element, if it exists.
    var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg").data([data]);
  //Otherwise, create the skeletal chart.
    var gEnter = svg.enter().append("svg").append("g");
    // Update the outer dimensions.
    svg.attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
    // Update the inner dimensions.
    var g = svg.select("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");  
   console.log(svg.select("#clip-before"+this.id));
          var currNode=this;      
    if(svg.select("#clip-before"+this.id)[0][0]!=null){     
       svg.select("#clip-before"+this.id+" rect")
       .transition().duration(400)
       .attr("width", xScale(parsedate(today)))
    .attr("height", height- margin.top - margin.bottom);
    
    svg.select("#clip-after"+this.id+" rect")
       .transition().duration(400)
       .attr("x", xScale(parsedate(today)))
       .attr("width", width-xScale(parsedate(today)))
    .attr("height", height- margin.top - margin.bottom);
     
      svg.selectAll("path.line-after")
      .data(data).transition()
             .duration(400).attr("d", line_after(data));
             
             svg.selectAll("path.line-before")
      .data(data).transition()
             .duration(400).attr("d", line_before(data));
             
             svg.select("line.today")
       .transition().duration(400)
       .attr({'x1': xScale(parsedate(today)),'y1': 0,'x2': xScale(parsedate(today)),'y2': height- margin.top - margin.bottom})
    .style("stroke", "#FF7F66")
    .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3")) 
    .style("fill", "none");              
    }else{
     g.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip-before"+this.id)
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", xScale(parsedate(today)))
      .attr("height", height- margin.top - margin.bottom);
      
    g.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip-after"+this.id)
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", xScale(parsedate(today)))
      .attr("width", width-xScale(parsedate(today)))
      .attr("height", height- margin.top - margin.bottom);
      
     g.selectAll(".line")
      .data(["after"])
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "line-" + d; })
      .attr("clip-path", function(d) { return "url(#clip-"+d+currNode.id+")"; })
      .attr("d", line_after(data));
      
    g.selectAll(".line")
      .data(["before"])
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "line-" + d; })
      .attr("clip-path", function(d) { return "url(#clip-"+d+currNode.id+")"; })
      .attr("d", line_before(data));
      
   g.append("line")
    .attr("class","today")
    .attr({
     'x1': xScale(parsedate(today)),
     'y1': 0,
     'x2': xScale(parsedate(today)),
     'y2': height- margin.top - margin.bottom
    })
    .style("stroke", "#FF7F66")
    .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3")) 
    .style("fill", "none");   
    }
  // Add the X Axis
    g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis");
    //.call(xAxis);
    
    svg.select(".x.axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0,300)").transition().duration(400).call(xAxis);
           
    g.selectAll(".x.axis text")  // select all the text elements for the xaxis
     .attr("transform", function(d) {
     return "translate(" + this.getBBox().height*-2 + "," + this.getBBox().height + ")rotate(-45)";
    });

    // Add the Y Axis
    g.append("g")
     .attr("class", "y axis"); //.call(yAxis)
   
    svg.select(".y.axis").transition().duration(400).call(yAxis);  
        alreadyClicked = true;
  });
   }

   // The x-accessor for the path generator; xScale ∘ xValue.
   function X(d) {
  return xScale(formatDate.parse(d.date));
   }

   // The y-accessor for the path generator; yScale ∘ yValue.
   function Y(d) {
  return yScale(d.actualvalue);
   }
  
   function Y2(d){
  return yScale(d.predictedvalue);
   }

   chart.margin = function(_) {
  if (!arguments.length) return margin;
  margin = _;
  return chart;
   };

   chart.width = function(_) {
  if (!arguments.length) return width;
  width = _;
  return chart;
   };

   chart.height = function(_) {
  if (!arguments.length) return height;
  height = _;
  return chart;
   };

   chart.x = function(_) {
  if (!arguments.length) return xValue;
  xValue = _;
  return chart;
   };

   chart.y = function(_) {
  if (!arguments.length) return yValue;
  yValue = _;
  return chart;
   };
   function getWidth(width){
 
   if (width > 1500 || width < 990) {
    return 800;
   }else if ( width > 1300 && width > 990){
    return 700;
   }else{
    return 650;
   }
  }  
    return chart;
 };
})();

/*PredictGraph code end*/


/*app.js code start*/

  var chart = d3.PredictGraph(); 
  //Global Variables
  
  var formatDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
  var today = formatDate(moment()._d) || "2016-01-01";
  var first_day = formatDate(getFirstDay()) || "2015-01-01";
  var numMonths = "three";  //one, three, six, twelve
  var last_day = formatDate(getLastDay(numMonths)) || "2016-04-01";
  var product = "product1";
  var loaded = false;
  // called everytime a user clicks on a month button or select a dropdown menu item
  // input params: the firstDay (today minus 12 months), lastDay (pass value retrieved from numMonths into getLastDay)
  //      productSelected (selected product based on dropdown menu value)
  function updateResults(firstDay, lastDay, productSelected){
  
   //get data... will get from Django eventually instead of json file
   //d3.json("data/data.json",function(data){ 
          var data=[{"date":"2015-01-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":512,"predictedvalue":05},{"date":"2015-02-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":311,"predictedvalue":426},{"date":"2015-03-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":305,"predictedvalue":725},{"date":"2015-04-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":396,"predictedvalue":887},{"date":"2015-05-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":70,"predictedvalue":299},{"date":"2015-06-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":32,"predictedvalue":40},{"date":"2015-07-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":157,"predictedvalue":504},{"date":"2015-08-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":335,"predictedvalue":372},{"date":"2015-09-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":426,"predictedvalue":899},{"date":"2015-10-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":983,"predictedvalue":842},{"date":"2015-11-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":701,"predictedvalue":569},{"date":"2015-12-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":674,"predictedvalue":387},{"date":"2016-01-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":986,"predictedvalue":65},{"date":"2016-02-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":426,"predictedvalue":49},{"date":"2016-03-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":130,"predictedvalue":63},{"date":"2016-04-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":674,"predictedvalue":889},{"date":"2016-05-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":192,"predictedvalue":983},{"date":"2016-06-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":6,"predictedvalue":186},{"date":"2016-07-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":476,"predictedvalue":181},{"date":"2016-08-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":493,"predictedvalue":544},{"date":"2016-09-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":121,"predictedvalue":792},{"date":"2016-10-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":745,"predictedvalue":712},{"date":"2016-11-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":755,"predictedvalue":46},{"date":"2016-12-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":361,"predictedvalue":810},{"date":"2015-01-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":675,"predictedvalue":722},{"date":"2015-02-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":690,"predictedvalue":388},{"date":"2015-03-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":994,"predictedvalue":871},{"date":"2015-04-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":678,"predictedvalue":656},{"date":"2015-05-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":901,"predictedvalue":216},{"date":"2015-06-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":304,"predictedvalue":491},{"date":"2015-07-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":223,"predictedvalue":360},{"date":"2015-08-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":299,"predictedvalue":487},{"date":"2015-09-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":80,"predictedvalue":267},{"date":"2015-10-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":760,"predictedvalue":830},{"date":"2015-11-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":122,"predictedvalue":273},{"date":"2015-12-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":859,"predictedvalue":258},{"date":"2016-01-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":807,"predictedvalue":729},{"date":"2016-02-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":82,"predictedvalue":939},{"date":"2016-03-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":72,"predictedvalue":348},{"date":"2016-04-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":544,"predictedvalue":429},{"date":"2016-05-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":512,"predictedvalue":562},{"date":"2016-06-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":510,"predictedvalue":800},{"date":"2016-07-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":283,"predictedvalue":847},{"date":"2016-08-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":172,"predictedvalue":343},{"date":"2016-09-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":315,"predictedvalue":633},{"date":"2016-10-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":863,"predictedvalue":184},{"date":"2016-11-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":125,"predictedvalue":623},{"date":"2016-12-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":400,"predictedvalue":920}];
    // get data between first and last day and for the selected product
    // draw a single line as a test
    var test_data = data.filter(function(el){
     return el.date < lastDay && el.date > firstDay && el.productname == productSelected
    });
   d3.select("#graph1").datum(test_data).call(chart);
   //});
  }
  
  function updateResults2(firstDay, lastDay, productSelected){ 
   //get data... will get from Django eventually instead of json file
   //d3.json("data/data.json",function(data){
  var data=[{"date":"2015-01-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":512,"predictedvalue":805},{"date":"2015-02-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":311,"predictedvalue":426},{"date":"2015-03-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":305,"predictedvalue":725},{"date":"2015-04-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":396,"predictedvalue":887},{"date":"2015-05-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":70,"predictedvalue":299},{"date":"2015-06-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":32,"predictedvalue":40},{"date":"2015-07-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":157,"predictedvalue":504},{"date":"2015-08-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":335,"predictedvalue":372},{"date":"2015-09-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":426,"predictedvalue":899},{"date":"2015-10-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":983,"predictedvalue":842},{"date":"2015-11-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":701,"predictedvalue":569},{"date":"2015-12-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":674,"predictedvalue":387},{"date":"2016-01-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":986,"predictedvalue":65},{"date":"2016-02-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":426,"predictedvalue":49},{"date":"2016-03-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":130,"predictedvalue":63},{"date":"2016-04-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":674,"predictedvalue":889},{"date":"2016-05-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":192,"predictedvalue":983},{"date":"2016-06-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":6,"predictedvalue":186},{"date":"2016-07-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":476,"predictedvalue":181},{"date":"2016-08-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":493,"predictedvalue":544},{"date":"2016-09-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":121,"predictedvalue":792},{"date":"2016-10-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":745,"predictedvalue":712},{"date":"2016-11-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":755,"predictedvalue":46},{"date":"2016-12-01","productname":"product1","actualvalue":361,"predictedvalue":810},{"date":"2015-01-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":675,"predictedvalue":722},{"date":"2015-02-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":690,"predictedvalue":388},{"date":"2015-03-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":994,"predictedvalue":871},{"date":"2015-04-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":678,"predictedvalue":656},{"date":"2015-05-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":901,"predictedvalue":216},{"date":"2015-06-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":304,"predictedvalue":491},{"date":"2015-07-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":223,"predictedvalue":360},{"date":"2015-08-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":299,"predictedvalue":487},{"date":"2015-09-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":80,"predictedvalue":267},{"date":"2015-10-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":760,"predictedvalue":830},{"date":"2015-11-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":122,"predictedvalue":273},{"date":"2015-12-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":859,"predictedvalue":258},{"date":"2016-01-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":807,"predictedvalue":729},{"date":"2016-02-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":82,"predictedvalue":939},{"date":"2016-03-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":72,"predictedvalue":348},{"date":"2016-04-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":544,"predictedvalue":429},{"date":"2016-05-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":512,"predictedvalue":562},{"date":"2016-06-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":510,"predictedvalue":800},{"date":"2016-07-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":283,"predictedvalue":847},{"date":"2016-08-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":172,"predictedvalue":343},{"date":"2016-09-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":315,"predictedvalue":633},{"date":"2016-10-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":863,"predictedvalue":184},{"date":"2016-11-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":125,"predictedvalue":623},{"date":"2016-12-01","productname":"product2","actualvalue":400,"predictedvalue":920}];
    
    // get data between first and last day and for the selected product
    // draw a single line as a test
    var test_data = data.filter(function(el){
     return el.date < lastDay && el.date > firstDay && el.productname == productSelected
    });
    d3.select("#graph2").datum(test_data).call(chart);  
   //});
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){  
   $("#button30").click( function(){
    $(".buttons1").removeClass("selected-button");
    $("#button30").addClass("selected-button");
    numMonths= $("#button30").data('months'); 
    first_day=formatDate(getFirstDay());
    last_day=formatDate(getLastDay(numMonths)); 
    updateResults(first_day,last_day,product);
   });
   
   $("#button90").click( function(){
    $(".buttons1").removeClass("selected-button");
    $("#button90").addClass("selected-button");
    numMonths= $("#button90").data('months');
    first_day=formatDate(getFirstDay());
    last_day=formatDate(getLastDay(numMonths)); 
    updateResults(first_day,last_day,product);
   });
   
   $("#button180").click( function(){
    $(".buttons1").removeClass("selected-button");
    $("#button180").addClass("selected-button");
    numMonths= $("#button180").data('months');
    first_day=formatDate(getFirstDay());
    last_day=formatDate(getLastDay(numMonths)); 
    updateResults(first_day,last_day,product);
   });
   
   $("#button360").click( function(){
    $(".buttons1").removeClass("selected-button");
    $("#button360").addClass("selected-button");
    numMonths= $("#button360").data('months');
    first_day=formatDate(getFirstDay());
    last_day=formatDate(getLastDay(numMonths)); 
    updateResults(first_day,last_day,product);
   });
   
   updateResults(first_day,last_day,product);
   $("#button30-2").click( function(){
    $(".buttons2").removeClass("selected-button");
    $("#button30-2").addClass("selected-button");
    numMonths= $("#button30-2").data('months');
    first_day=formatDate(getFirstDay());
    last_day=formatDate(getLastDay(numMonths)); 
    updateResults2(first_day,last_day,product);
   });
   
   $("#button90-2").click( function(){
    $(".buttons2").removeClass("selected-button");
    $("#button90-2").addClass("selected-button");
    numMonths= $("#button90-2").data('months');
    first_day=formatDate(getFirstDay());
    last_day=formatDate(getLastDay(numMonths));
    updateResults2(first_day,last_day,product);
   });
   
   $("#button180-2").click( function(){
    $(".buttons2").removeClass("selected-button");
    $("#button180-2").addClass("selected-button");
    numMonths= $("#button180-2").data('months'); 
    first_day=formatDate(getFirstDay());
    last_day=formatDate(getLastDay(numMonths));  
    updateResults2(first_day,last_day,product);
   });
   
   $("#button360-2").click( function(){
    $(".buttons2").removeClass("selected-button");
    $("#button360-2").addClass("selected-button");
    numMonths= $("#button360-2").data('months'); //or .data()
    first_day=formatDate(getFirstDay());
    last_day=formatDate(getLastDay(numMonths));  // to set last day
    updateResults2(first_day,last_day,product);
   });
   
   updateResults2(first_day,last_day,product);

     });
   // function to set last day date... basically today + 1, 3, 6, or 12 months, default is 3
   function getLastDay(months){ 

    switch(months){
     case "one": 
    
      return moment().add(1, 'months')._d; 
     break;
     case"six": 
    
      return moment().add(6, 'months')._d; 
     break;
     case"twelve":  
     
      return moment().add(12, 'months')._d; 
     break; 
     default: 
      return moment().add(3, 'months')._d; 
    };

   }
   
   // function to set first day date... basically today - 12
   function getFirstDay(){
    return moment().subtract(12,'months')._d;
   }
```

```css
.container{
  margin-top:50px;}
html, body {
  height: 100%; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
.wrap{
  min-heigh:100%;
}
.prediction{
  height:700px;
}
.footer{
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;padding:0px;text-align:center;}
.footer p{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
    .selected-button{background-color: black;border-color: black;color:white;}
  
 .axis path,
 .axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
 }
 .x.axis path {} .line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
 }

 .line-before {
  stroke:#2185C5;
  fill: none;
 }
 .line-after{
  stroke:#FFB779;
  fill: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jhjanicki.github.io/reusable-line-chart/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jhjanicki.github.io/reusable-line-chart/js/moment.js"></script>
    <!-- D3 --><script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <!-- underscore --><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="main">
<section class="prediction" id="prediction1">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="buttons">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default buttons1" data-months="one" id="button30"> 1 Month</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default selected-button buttons1" data-months="three" id="button90"> 3 Months</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default buttons1" data-months="six" id="button180"> 6 Months</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default buttons1" data-months="twelve" id="button360"> 12 Months</button>
</div>
<div id="graph1">
</div>
</div>
</div> <!-- end row -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="buttons">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default buttons2" data-months="one" id="button30-2"> 1 Month</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default selected-button buttons2" data-months="three" id="button90-2"> 3 Months</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default buttons2" data-months="six" id="button180-2"> 6 Months</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default buttons2" data-months="twelve" id="button360-2"> 12 Months</button>
</div>
<div id="graph2"></div>
</div></div> <!-- end row -->
  </section> 
 </div> <!-- end container -->
```

I've gone through your http://jhjanicki.github.io/reusable-line-chart/   and seen app.js line number 110  updateResults(first_day,last_day,product); this line will invoke for first graph and makes `alreadyClicked` value to `true` at line number 206, and when you invoke `updateResults2(first_day,last_day,product);` at line number 151 for second graph 'alreadyClicked' value is set to `true` earlier now else part will not be executed and this time it'll try to animate, but actually there is no such element exists. We have to maintain separate clip-path for each svg, then only we can achieve that. Try to analyze the code and understand. Hope this is what you are looking for. If not ask me :D

Comment: That makes sense! actually I noticed today that it could be something to do with alreadyClicked, but when I add a setter to the chart function for alreadyClicked and set it to false it still didn't work (i.e. `var chart2 = d3.PredictGraph().alreadyClicked(false); d3.select("#graph2").datum(data).call(chart2);`) . But your solution is working really well . Thank you so much!

Comment: p.s. I tried to upvote your answer since I really appreciate that you went over my code and that I got to learn something but I guess since I just started I don't have enough reputation to do so yet.  But really thanks!

Comment: Okay, it's alright. It's pleasure to help and glad you understood it pretty well.: D